# Apache Commons UrlValidator

Tags: java, validation, apache-commons

I have the following java code:

```
UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator();
boolean validUrl = urlValidator.isValid("http://www.google.com");
System.out.println("result: " + validUrl);
```

When I run the above code, I always get:

> result: false

Why does apache commons UrlValidator not regard "http://www.google.com" as valid? If I replace "http://www.google.com" with "http://www.google.com/index.php", I get "result: true". However, my users do have a legitimate use for submitting URLs which do not end in a specific filename.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using older version of commons validator. This bug was resolved post release 1.2.

Try using latest validator version(1.3.1) and it should work fine.

Comment: It looks like I'm using version 1.1.4 from 2006. Unfortunately, my client does not approve of "upgrading" versions so I'll have to look for another workaround. Since this is the technically correct answer, I've marked it as accepted.

Comment: Hey, I am also using URLValidator for the link given below. https://www.dropbox.com/s/iosxmpsj3ybmosk/LC9032THB%20BLK...JPG?m= But  it is throwing an error in that link. I changed the link to https://www.dropbox.com/s/iosxmpsj3ybmosk/LC9032THB%20BLK..JPG?m= It started working fine. The only difference between the 2 links is that the first one has 3 dots and the second one has two dots. ANy ideas why this is happening.

Comment: Apache commons validator doesn't consider three dots as valid url. This was atleast the case with apache commons I was working with.